error on running web app in flutter on android studio
I was running the app the day before and it was working functionally , today i got this error
Rejecting promise with error: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'nativeCommunication')
A message on the flutter/lifecycle channel was discarded before it could be handled.
This happens when a plugin sends messages to the framework side before the framework has had an opportunity to register a listener. See the ChannelBuffers API documentation for details on how to configure the channel to expect more messages, or to expect messages to get discarded:
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ChannelBuffers-class.html
I tried
flutter --clean
flutter --pub get
flutter --run
the problem is still found and the web page doesn't respond it gives me white page

Add the following line to your web/index.html file inside <body></body>
<script type="application/javascript" src="/assets/packages/flutter_inappwebview/assets/web/web_support.js" defer></script>

